# Insert DataRow with a path string cause MaxLength error

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, dataset

I have a dataset with a `varchar(500)` column, in this column I'm trying to insert a value such as `"c://documents/ecc.. "` , it's a dynamic local path to some files.

The length of the path is less than 500 characters but I get an error, something like: `"impossible to set the value in pathcolumn. The value violate the MaxLength parameter of the column".` If I insert some non-path string, all works correctly. This is the code I have used to insert the path value:

```
DataRow newCustomersRow = DataBaseMioDataSet.Tables["Gallery"].NewRow();
newCustomersRow["pathimg"] = destinationPath;
DataBaseMyDataSet.Tables["Gallery"].Rows.Add(newCustomersRow);
TabAdapter.Update(DataBaseMyDataSet.Gallery);
```

How I can do to avoid MaxLength error?

Comment: Just a wild guess, verify if there is white-space in your path.

Comment: What is the exact length of destinationPath? Consider Unicode has two bytes for char.

Comment: There's no spaces in my path, the length is 93 chars

Comment: I can only suggest to use the debugger to step through this code and verify the actual values of the DataColumn named "pathimg" inside the datatable "gallery", in particular the actual value of MaxLength property.

Comment: Thanks Steve i have found the solution during the debugging... I have two different maxlenght , 500 in the database and the 50 in the Dataset for the same column. Change to 500 the dataset maxlenght solve the problem.